# How to check the PDF page is coloured or not in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, colors

I am having PDF that contains N number of pages. How can I count the coloured and non-coloured(Black and white) pages.

Example : If I give 100 pages PDF file as input, it should say X number of pages are coloured and y number of pages are non-coloured.

Comment: Depends, do you have images in it or just black and white text or colored text?

Comment: Probably it may have image also...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert the PDF to images (e.g. with pdf2image) and then analyse the different channels. For example using HSV the H and S channel should be 0 or near 0, if the page contains only black and white.

```
import pdf2image
import numpy as np

images = convert_from_path('example.pdf')
sw=0
color=0
for image in images:
    img = np.array(image.convert('HSV'))
    hsv_sum = img.sum(0).sum(0)
    if hsv_sum[0] == 0 and hsv_sum[1] == 0:
        sw += 1
    else:
        color += 1
```

Gives me sw=1 and color=1 for an example pdf with one site black text and one side red text, each on white background.

You may need to search for hsv_sum[0:1] smaller than a portion of pixels, if the background is not completely white and the text completely black (scanned PDFs e.g.).

Comment: It's not a best solution. To get the count, I have to split it as image then I have to get the count. Finally I have to delete the files. If the file count is high means it's not a good solution. But thanks for your answer

Comment: Edited my answer to try better explain my point. Also used to work on the pictures in memory as @sunnytown mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @sunnytown. I got solution

Comment: It should be: `from pdf2image import convert_from_path`

Comment: This is genius. When H and S are zero, you get all grayscale tones by varying V. But if you deviate H and/or S, it becomes color, but at low values not noticeable by eye.

Comment: Yes, that's how HSV (hue, saturation, value) works.